# Laravel OneToMany query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel and the Eloquent model and I find it difficult to understand the simplest queries even after reading the documentation.

I have two models Measure and MeasureType, and I want to select all measures of a certain type. What in sql would be like:

```
select * from measures m
      join measure_types mt on mt.id=m.measure_type_id
      join measure_type_trans t on t.measure_type_id=mt.id
      where t.name='xyz';
```

In Measure I have:

```
public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(MeasureType::class, 'measure_type_id');
    }
```

And in MeasureType:

```
public function measures()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Measure::class);
    }
```

Name column is in the translatable table measure_type_trans
How do I do such simple query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the type and nested in it the measures that belong to it

```
$measureType = MeasureTypeTrans::where('name', 'xyz')->with('type.measures')->first();

//you can access the measures with the attribute having the same name as the relation
$measures = $measureType->type->measures;
```

If you want to have only the measures as a collection (almost the same as the query you posted)

```
$name = 'xyz';
$measures = Measure::whereHas('type', function ($typeQueryBuilder) use($name) {
    $typeQueryBuilder->whereHas('typeTrans', function($typeTransQB) use($name) {
        $typeTransQB->where('name', $name);
    });
})->get();
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, the column 'name' is translatable, how do I do in that case?

Comment: Solved with this:
$measureTypeTrans = MeasureTypeTrans::where('name', 'xyz')->first();
        $measureType = MeasureType::where('id', $measureTypeTrans->measure_type_id)->first();
        $measures = $measureType->measures;

Comment: @Jaime that required 3 queries, edited the answer to do in in only one query with joins (second example) (relation names migh not be exact, adapt them as they are in your code)